# Issue an integral involving a $\log$

Tags: integration, logarithms

Let $$F(t)=\frac{t+7}{2+t}$$ and $$E(t)=\frac{\ln(t+4)}{t+2}\,.$$ My job is to compute the area between them from $x=0$ to $x=5$, which got me from
$$\int_0^5{F(t)-E(t)}$$ to $$\int_0^5{\frac{t+7-\ln(t+4)}{t+2}}\,.$$ 
How can I solve it?

Comment: It's integration is complex and results in a polylogarithm expression. Are you sure you got it right ? If polylogarithms etc are what you study then it's correct but if you've never heard of it then take a look into it again !

Comment: @Eric Schwarz I have reformatted your question a lot, feel free to undo if it is not consistent with your question